# Setup LXD storage thin pool on an existing LVM volume group of the host

Tags: 19.10, lvm, lxd

The `lxd init` wizzard does not allow to (re)use the existing LVM volume group of the host for LXD storage pool.

How to configure LXD storage manually, so that it creates thin pool and volumes in the existing volume group of the host?

Answer (score 7):

In the `lxd init` wizzard, answer `no` to a question about creating a storage pool.

```
Do you want to configure a new storage pool? (yes/no) [default=yes]: no
```

The following commands need to be executed with root privileges. Switch to root with `sudo -i` command or execute the following commands with `sudo` prefix.

In this code snippet, `<VG>` is the host's volume group name. Use `vgs` command to find your volume group name. This command creates a LXD storage pool with a name `pool` in the LVM volume group `<VG>`. The pool's name in host's LVM becomes `lxd-pool`.

```
# lxc storage create pool lvm source=<VG> lvm.vg.force_reuse=true lvm.use_thinpool=true lvm.thinpool_name=lxd-pool
```

Afterwards, make it a default pool for the containers' disks.

```
# lxc profile device add default root disk path=/ pool=pool
```

To check if it worked as intended, use `lvs` and check if `lxd-pool` is listed...

```
# lvs
  LV                   VG      Attr       LSize   Pool Origin      Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lxd-pool             <VG>    twi-a-tz-- 162,00g                  0,00   1,63
(...)
```

... and `lxc storage list` to check the LXD storage configuration:

```
# lxc storage list
+------+-------------+--------+---------+---------+
| NAME | DESCRIPTION | DRIVER | SOURCE  | USED BY |
+------+-------------+--------+---------+---------+
| pool |             | lvm    | <VG>    | 3       |
+------+-------------+--------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Resources which were helpful in a research: https://lxd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/storage/, https://www.pither.com/simon/blog/2018/09/28/lxd-lvm-thinpool-setup

Comment: Thanks for posting this! It was very helpful :)

Comment: lxd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/storage is now https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/docs/master/storage

Comment: it works! amazing

Comment: Documentation has moved again: https://documentation.ubuntu.com/lxd/en/latest/explanation/storage/